# How can I parallelize this code using OpenMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, multicore

I have a function, computer_a. I want to parallelize this code in OpenMP, but I do not know what is the wrong with code. When iterations of the loops increase using changing lower/upper bound of the loops, something went wrong without any error!

I want to parallelize one the loops a, b, c, or d. I think the best one would be loop a. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Would you mind guide me about any mistakes I have done in the code please?

```
void compute_a(int al, int au, int bl, int bu, int cl, int cu, int dl, int du, float *var, float *cv, float *sdi, float *sdeg, int *cc)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int a=al; a<=au; a++)
    {
        int up[n][5];
        int down[n][5];
        int up_i=0;
        int down_i=0;
        for(int b=bl; b<=bu; b++)
        {
            for(int c=cl; c<=cu; c++)
            {
                for(int d=dl; d<=du; d++)
                {
                    float result[n];
                    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                    {
                        result[i]=a*(1-var[i])+b*(1-cv[i])+c*sdi[i]+d*sdeg[i];
                    }
                    int ccc[n]
                    for(int kk=0; kk<n; kk++)
                        ccc[kk]=cc[kk];

                    quickSortd2(result, ccc, 0, n-1);
                    int count_of_ones=0;
                    for(int ii=0; ii<1000; ii++)
                        if(ccc[ii]==1)
                            count_of_ones++;
                    if(count_of_ones>150)
                    {
                        up[up_i][0]=a;
                        up[up_i][1]=b;
                        up[up_i][2]=c;
                        up[up_i][3]=d;
                        up[up_i++][4]=count_of_ones;
                    }
                    else if(count_of_ones<121)
                    {
                        down[down_i][0]=a;
                        down[down_i][1]=b;
                        down[down_i][2]=c;
                        down[down_i][3]=d;
                        down[down_i++][4]=count_of_ones;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        FILE *fpup;
        FILE *fpdown;

        char* path_up_p1="ResultUp150forA (";
        char* path_up_p2=").csv";
        char* path_down_p1="ResultDn121forA (";
        char* path_down_p2=").csv";
        char *path_up;
        char *path_down;


        char str_file_number[5];
        itoa(a, str_file_number, 10);
        path_up=(char*)malloc(strlen(path_up_p1)+strlen(str_file_number)+strlen(path_up_p2)+1);
        path_up[0]='\0';
        strcat(path_up,path_up_p1);
        strcat(path_up,str_file_number);
        strcat(path_up,path_up_p2);
        fpup=fopen(path_up, "w");
        for(int t=0; t<up_i; t++)
            fprintf(fpup, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", up[t][0], up[t][1], up[t][2], up[t][3], up[t][4]);
        fclose(fpup);

        path_down=(char*)malloc(strlen(path_down_p1)+strlen(str_file_number)+strlen(path_down_p2)+1);
        path_down[0]='\0';
        strcat(path_down,path_down_p1);
        strcat(path_down,str_file_number);
        strcat(path_down,path_down_p2);
        fpdown=fopen(path_down, "w");
        for(int t=0; t<up_i; t++)
            fprintf(fpdown, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", down[t][0], down[t][1], down[t][2], down[t][3], down[t][4]);
        fclose(fpdown);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the openmp flag to your compilation? For example if using GCC you need to specify -fopenmp.

Comment: Looks like you have a few race conditions.

Comment: @TimB Yes, I compile the code using -std=c99 -fopenmp -Wall flags.

Comment: @shawn, Would you mind please tell me in which lines the race conditions are happening?

Comment: @Shawn: I do not understand how could there be any race conditions while all variables are defined local (private) within the loop a?